# How to implement a loading progress bar when exporting to XLS (Maatwebsite Excel 3.1)

Tags: laravel

Is it possible  to show the loading progress bar into the client while the file is generating? And also display a message when the file is done.

I tried to do with ajax, but it doesn't work.

```
return Excel::download(new UserExport($list), "somefilename.xlsx");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927757/laravel-excel-upload-and-progressbar